# java.io.IOException while downloading signed jar using JNLP

Tags: java-web-start, jnlp, ioexception

I have signed my app jar using jks exported from my Websphere Application server. I am getting following error

java.io.IOException: Cannot find cached resource for URL: http://aaa.com/RAISAISLogonWeb/LogonApp.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.getCachedResourceFilePath(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getCachedResourceFilePath(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.getSignedJNLPBits(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.getSignedJNLPFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedLaunchDescHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Here is my jnlp

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://camdv1lwsl01.cammis.local/RAISAISLogonWeb/">
  <information>
    <title>Logon App</title>
    <vendor>aaa.com</vendor>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <property name="jnlp.publish-url" value="http://aaa.com/LogonWeb/"/>
    <j2se version="1.7*" java-vm-args="-Xmx32m" max-heap-size="32m" href="http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp"/>
    <jar href="LogonApp.jar" main="true" download="eager"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc name="Logon App" main-class="com.aaa.LogonApp">
    <argument>xkckdfdwfwffwff</argument>
  </application-desc>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
</jnlp>
```

Please help me to solve the issue.
Thanks

Comment: I solved this by disabling cach in Control Panel->Java->General Setting (Tab)-> Uncheck the option "Keep Temporary files on my computer".

Comment: Now I get this error this error:-
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334101/nullpointerexception-while-downloading-signed-jar-using-jnlp](nullpointerexception-while-downloading-signed-jar-using-jnlp)